How to target HTML element with no unique identifier - Selenium and BeautifulSoup
I'm using BeautifulSoup and Selenium for web scraping reviews on Goodreads. I'm able to get the results I want, but I want to use Actions to click the "show more reviews" button so that the page keeps loading and I can repeat the code to get more reviews.
Here is what the HTMl looks like:enter image description here There is no 'unique' identifier like an ID to use to target the "show more reviews" button; the class is the same as other buttons on the page. I'm not sure how to target this specifically.
I've tried all kinds of "By.__" variations I can think of, even XPath.

You'll have to use enough common identifiers to make it unique. Or simply target Nth Span Element or Nth span element inside X element inside Y element inside Z element inside this unique element

Provide text, not images of text.

You can search for the text node and work from there. (This isn't as simple as it is for other elements but it's do-able.) XPath is probably the easiest way but you'll need to improve your xpath knowledge.

You can press F12 in the browser to locate the span element, then right-click Copy ->Copy XPath or Copy full XPath to obtain the position of the span element.

This was helpful!
I'm getting an empty array as a result.

All right, the element you want to parse may not exist. You need to output the response content to confirm that the XPath matches.

You can write your own custom finding functions. You also don't have to limit yourself to attributes of the precise tag you're looking for. You can look at [the properties of] its parents, siblings, or children, too, among other things.
For example, if these span tags are uniquely in the sense that they contain an <i> element containing the Icon and ChevronIcon classes, you might do something like this:
def my_interesting_span(tag):
    if tag.name == 'span':
        icon_tag = tag.find('i')  # look for a descendant i tag
        if icon_tag:
            classes = icon_tag.get('class', '')
            if 'Icon' in classes and 'IconChevron' in classes:
                return True
    return False

# ...
expand_span = soup.find(my_interesting_span) # or use `find_all`


You may also be able to find other patterns or situations that work in your context.
